# Find solutions for the equation $a^3 + b^3 = c^2$ in integers $c\geq b\geq a\geq1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The equation $a^3 + b^3 = c^2$ where in integers c≥b≥a≥1.

i)Find a primite solution that have $a=b$

ii)Find primite solution that has $a$ $a>10000$

iii)If $(A,B,C)$ is a solution to the equation and n is any integers, show that $(An^2,Bn^2,Cn^3)$ is also a solution to the equaiton

I have no idea where i start to solve it. But i found a solution $(2,2,4)$

Comment: Hint;  if $2a^3=c^2$ deduce that $c$ is even.  And if $a^3=2C^2$ deduce that $a$ is even.

Comment: You might look at [OEIS sequence A050802](https://oeis.org/A050802) and related sequences.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1618739/the-equation-a3-b3-c2-has-solution-a-b-c-2-2-4) for some relevant discussions.

Comment: Thanks for your advices.

Comment: What is a "primite" solution?

Comment: a^3+b^3=c^2 and the triple is called primitive if gcd(a,b)=1

Answer (score 1):

1) $a^3+b^3=2b^3=c^2$, both $c$ and $b$ must be even, substitute $c=2c_1$ and $b=2b_1$ then $4b_1^3=c_1^2$. Again $c_1$ must be even, substitute $c_1=2c_2$ then $b_1^3=c_2^2$. From here one possible solution $b_1=c_2=1$ then  $a=b=2$ and $c=4$.

2) Here we also can use the previous results. Let $c_2=1000$, then $a=b=2b_1=200$ and $c=4c_2=4000$.

3) $A^3+B^3-C^2=0$, multiply by $n^6$, then $(An^2)^3+(Bn^2)^3-(Cn^3)^2=0$

Answer (score 0):

Above equation shown below:

$a^3 + b^3 = c^2\dotsc(1)$

Equation $(1)$ has parameteric solution:

$a=pqr$

$b=pq(r-1)$

$c=(pq)^2$

Where,

$p=r^2-r+1$

$q=2r-1$

For, $r=3$, we get:

$(105)^3+(70)^3=1225^2$

For, $a>10^4$

Take, $r=10$ and we get:

$(a,b,c)=(17290,15561,2989441)$